# HID Detecting Device

Tags: hid

I have a code which helps me in detecting all the USB devices connected into my PC. But I want to detect only the HID devices connected to my PC.
The code which I have written is

```
WqlEventQuery insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'");

ManagementEventWatcher insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);

insertWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceInsertedEvent);

insertWatcher.Start();
```

Is there any query where we can fetch only the HID(Human Interface Device) connected devices.